# Netbeans showing no local branches when trying to push to git repo

Tags: php, git, netbeans

I'm new to using Github and I'm trying to get my PHP project in Netbeans to work with Github.

I created a new PHP project from existing sources with the source folder as my network drive which is also being used as the FTP location for my web server. I saved the metadata to my local drive. The git files location is on my local drive with my metadata.

I was able to create initialize repository without any problems but when I try to push my project up to my git repo it shows no local branches I can select.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was able to create initialize repository

Once the repo is created, you need to **[add](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#add)** and [make an initial commit](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#committing), in order for a branch (master) to be created.

[image: https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/74/ide/git/commit-small.png]

Then you would be able to select said master branch in order to push.

Comment: @MadushanPerera You are welcome. I am glad this answer is helpful.